# PickerView returns only the last Object added in my array

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, uipickerview

I am parsing some data from a JSON file

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"airports" ofType:@"json"];

NSString *jsonData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

NSArray *airports = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];


for (NSDictionary *result in airports)
{

    NSLog(@"%@ ", [result objectForKey:@"name"]);
    airportsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [airportsArray addObject:[result objectForKey:@"name"]];


}
```

NSLOG shows correctly all the airports but when the pickerView shows only the last airport in my file.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
return 1
;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:    (NSInteger)component
 {
return [airportsArray count];
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row  forComponent:    (NSInteger)component
{
return [airportsArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

UPDATE: Thanks for the replies. I fixed my code. I was simply allocating the Array inside the For in loop.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"airports" ofType:@"json"];

NSString *jsonData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

NSArray *airports = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];

    airportsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


for (NSDictionary *result in airports)
{

    NSLog(@"%@ ", [result objectForKey:@"name"]);
    [airportsArray addObject:[result objectForKey:@"name"]];


}
```

Comment: can you check content of your airportsArray using NSLog(@"%@", airportsArray);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is you are repeatedly creating the airportsArray. And you destroy what was in its place prior to this.

```
airportsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Move this line outside your `for...in` block.

Comment: Thank you so much! I haven't noticed that at all. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

**This is because you are allocating airportsArray everytime loop iterates**.

So allocate it once outside the loop as :

```
airportsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSDictionary *result in airports)
{

    NSLog(@"%@ ", [result objectForKey:@"name"]);
    [airportsArray addObject:[result objectForKey:@"name"]];
}
```

Comment: +1Thanks. bneely had already noticed my "little" mistakes! ;-)